# Using latestSuccessfulBuild number in Jenkins groovy job configuration

Tags: api, groovy, build, jenkins, config

I have a jenkins job and I want to use it's lastSuccessfulBuild number in my Build Flow groovy script.
I can get the last successful build number from Jenkins api at:

> http://{JENKINS_DOMAIN}/job/{JOB_NAME}/lastSuccessfulBuild/buildNumber

I tried using groovy's [RESTClient](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/rest.html) in my Build Flow groovy script but when importing the `groovyx.net.http.RESTClient` library I get syntax error.
Does any one know away of getting around this error or getting the api result in some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe this will help you:

```
import hudson.model.Build;
println(build.getProject().getLastSuccessfulBuild())
```

for example we have simple build flow groovy script building only one item "JobA". If we want check and print its last successful build we can write such script:

```
import hudson.model.Build;

def buildA = build("jobA")
println(buildA.getProject().getLastSuccessfulBuild())
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could expand your answer and provide some clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly a little overkill, but you can use HttpClient, as all you need is a get request on the url.

Here's one I knocked up from some code I had lying around

Tested it on our own Jenkins instance which has basic auth over ssl.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse
import org.apache.http.HttpVersion
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
import org.apache.http.client.params.ClientPNames
import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams
import org.apache.http.params.HttpProtocolParams


class LastSuccessfulBuild {
    def static main(args) {
        println new LastSuccessfulBuild().connect("your.jenkins.com", "443", "/path/to/job/YourJob/lastSuccessfulBuild/buildNumber", "your.user:your-password")
    }

    def connect(host, port, path, auth) {
        def url  = new URL("https", host, Integer.parseInt(port), path)
        HttpClient client = createClient()
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toURI())
        get.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic ${auth.getBytes().encodeBase64().toString()}")

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(get)
        def status = response.statusLine.statusCode
        if (status != 200) {
            throw new IOException("Failed to get page, status: $response.statusLine")
        }
        return response.entity.content.text
    }

    def createClient() {
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams()
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1)
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, "UTF-8")
        params.setBooleanParameter(ClientPNames.HANDLE_REDIRECTS, true)

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry()
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80))
        registry.register(new Scheme("https",SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(),443))

        ClientConnectionManager ccm = new PoolingClientConnectionManager(registry)
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 8000)
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 5400000)
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params)

        return client
    }

}
```